# PHP $_POST How to get a preset html field value not to show in email message

Tags: php

I have a html form which has a textarea with the text "Comments (optional)" and a field that has a preset value "Enter names here", and a php form handler that has a template for the email message.

```
<form>
<textarea name="comments" cols="30" rows="4">Comments (optional)</textarea>
<input type="text" name="join" value="Enter names here">
</form>

$message = "


Comments: " . $comments . "
Names: " . $person1 . " " . $join . " 

"
```

I am trying to have the email that comes through to show nothing after "Comments:" if nothing was entered into the field (ie. it still says "Comments (optional)" and to show the comment if the user has left a comment. The same applies for the text field, I want it to show nothing if the user didn't enter a name instead of showing "Enter names here" if no name was given by the user.

I am a beginner with php and I tried the following:

```
$emptyfield = ' ';

if ($comments != 'Comments (optional)') {
  $comments = $_POST["comments"];
} else {
  $comments = $emptyfield;
}


if ($join != 'Enter names here') {
  $join = 'joining with ' . $_POST["join"];
}
```

but the email message I get still shows

Comments: Comments (optional)

Names: ($person1) joining with Enter names here

I would be grateful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put "Comments (optional)" and "Enter names" here as placeholders in textarea/input like this:

```
<form>
<textarea name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Comments (optional)"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="join" placeholder="Enter names here">
</form>
```

Then in your php code you can do something like this:

```
$comments = isset($_POST["comments"]) ? $_POST["comments"] : ''; // check if the param is set
$join = isset($_POST["join"]) ? $_POST["join"] : ''; // check if the param is set

$message = ''
if (strlen($comments)) {
  $message .= 'Comments: ' . $comments;
}

if (strlen($join)) {
  $message .= 'joining with ' . $join;
}

// Do something with the message here
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a special attribute called `placeholder` in which you can provide some prompt. When user clicks on the `<input>` or
`<textarea>` and starts typing, `placeholder` will disappear. So, change your markup as:

```
<form>
    <textarea name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Comments (optional)"></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="join" placeholder="Enter names here" value="">
</form>
```

After submit you will get exactly what user input or empty string if nothing was input.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML content use placeholder to show the preset value. That is a good way.

```
<form>
<textarea name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Comments (optional)"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="join" placeholder="Enter names here">
</form>
```

And in your php code piece try to use the validations with isset() or !empty() or != null. here !isset() will check weather the variable is holding any value or not.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["join"])) {
  $join = 'joining with ' . $_POST["join"];
}
?>
```

Comment: I believe your php code is a little bit wrong, if "join" is not set in $_POST you are trying to access it, I think you should remove the not("!") from your if statement :)